# Best way to open dialog in MVC 4 application

Tags: dialog, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting to learn MVC so try to bear with me.

I have a table that has a few options to the side that you can edit, delete and show the details of.

[image]

If I click the Details button now It will take me to another page **(Details.cshtml)**
which is located in the same Controller as the **Index.cshtml** which displays the table above.

This is the code for the table **(Index.cshtml)**

```
@model Collusus.Models.IndexModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<h2>Hello @Html.ActionLink(Model.userLoggedIN, "getProfile")</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Change ID</th> 
    <th>Owner</th> 
    <th>Priority</th> 
    <th>Disposition Date</th> 
    <th>Completion Date</th> 
    <th>Do what?</th>
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
@for(int i=0; i<Model.changes.Count(); i++)
{
<tr> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].ID</td> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].Owner</td> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].Priority</td> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].DispositionDate.ToShortDateString()</td> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].ActualCompletionDate.ToShortDateString()</td> 
    <td>@if (Model.changes[i].Owner == Model.userLoggedIN)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=Model.changes[i].ID })
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.changes[i].ID })
        }
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=Model.changes[i].ID })
    </td>
</tr> 
}
</tbody> 
</table>
```

As you can see because of the code below, it will just take me to another page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=Model.changes[i].ID })
```

**What I want to do:**

- Open Delete,Edit or Details view in a dialog instead of another page.
- Be able to still have the same functionality as if they were just opening another page.

I don't know if that makes too much sense. I've tried to explain it the best I could and been frustrated searching Google / trying code from other solutions but can't get it to work.

If you suggest another way besides the JQUERY dialog I'm willing to go that option too. All help is appreciated since I've been so frustrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to open them into a modal dialog. To accomplish this you can return partial views from your controller.

You can add a class to your action links like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=Model.changes[i].ID }, new { @class = "details-modal" })
```

Your Details action method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // Your code here
    return PartialView("_Details", myModel); // return the partial view with the model
}
```

jQuery (off the top of my head so it may not be 100% correct):

```
$('#my-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});

$('.details-modal').click(function() {
    var theURL = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#my-dialog').load(theURL, function() {
        $(this).dialog('open');
    });

    return false; // ensures the browser is not redirected to the link's URL
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try it when I get home but this looks correct. I'll let you know.

Comment: I modified my code and tried it out but still doesn't work. It just doesn't do anything when I click the Details button. I've had the same problem with this looking at the other example so I don't know where to go from here. I did return true to see if he script reaches it and it just redirected me to the page. As far as the dialog working though, it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: I actually found another possible way of doing this and It might work so I'm going to do it a different way but your code helped so I'll accept it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Claud25 Are you loading the correct jQuery scripts in the appropriate order?

Comment: yes and like I said it looks good and it should work but it doesn't. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong on my part but I can't really see the problem.

Comment: Does this work if the partial view has a different model? If not how could you accomplish that?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Yes this will work if the partial view has a different model than the view.